# PHY model in LEACH CASTALIA

Tags: omnet++

I have installed LEACH protocol in CASTALIA (OMNET++). I want to know what PHY model LEACH is using. What is Channel model and Error model used in LEACH.

Comment: There is no official LEACH distribution in Castalia. It would be good to reference (and link) the one you are using.

Answer (score 1):

As far as I know (and I have not seen all implementations of LEACH in Castalia), LEACH in Castalia uses the existing PHY model that Castalia provides. In other words, the Radio model, and the wireless channel model of Castalia are used as is, and LEACH is built on top of them.

Note that this kind of implementation is superior to the models the initial LEACH publication used. The initial communication and energy models used in LEACH are too simplistic. It was understandable at the time of publication (2002) to use these very coarse approximations, but the research community has long moved away from these initial models.